# Unable to send image url to database

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I have set up a script that updates the database, all the form fields work, including the file upload, which does upload it to my server, my issue is that i want the url of the image to appear in the mysql table, so i can refer to it later (and it is linked to that entry, but everything i try it doesn't want to add it. Any ideas?

this is my form

```
<fieldset style="width:300px;">
<form method="post" action="./upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">>
Desc <input type="text" name="holdesc1"><br>
Dest <input type="text" name="holdest1"><br>
RRP <input type="text" name="rrp1"><br>
Cost Per <input type="text" name="cpe1"><br>
Entries Avail <input type="text" name="ea1"><br>
<label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</fieldset>
```

And this is my upload script

```
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "cl52-abcdef","abcdef") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("cl52-abcdef") or die(mysql_error()); 

   // Configuration - Your Options
      $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
      $max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
      $upload_path = './files/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

   $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
   $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

   // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
      die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

   // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
   if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

   // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!is_writable($upload_path))
      die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

   // We'll start handling the upload in the next step

?>


<?php
   // Configuration - Your Options
      $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
      $max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
      $upload_path = './files/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

   $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
   $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

   // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
      die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

   // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
   if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

   // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!is_writable($upload_path))
      die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

   // Upload the file to your specified path.
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
         echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; // It worked.
      else
         echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; // It failed :(.



if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$holdesc1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['holdesc1']);
$holdest1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['holdest1']);
$rrp1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rrp1']);
$cpe1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cpe1']);
$ea1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ea1']);
$filename=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['filename']);

$query1=mysql_query("insert into DealOne values('','$holdesc1','$holdest1','$rrp1','$cpe1','$ea1','$filename')");
echo "insert into DealOne values('','$holdesc1','$holdest1','$rrp1','$cpe1','$ea1''$filename',)";
if($query1)
{
header("location:list.php");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: https://github.com/simon-eQ/ImageUploader

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't what to add it? Are you trying to use $filename?

Comment: Basically i want the filename/url to appear in my mysql table, with the other fileds that I have added for that entry

Comment: You redeclare $filename in your condition statement. Use the $filename that you already declared above and not the post variable that doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code  do not have filename field.

```
$filename=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['filename']); // this field is not in form
```

you have input type file with name `userfile` so you need to use this field like

```
$userfile = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];  // this field is in form
```

secondly you should shift your file upload code inside `isset($_POST)`.

third try to use mysqli_* functions